# Is it possible to render blob images in a prawn document?

Tags: ruby, prawn

I´m willing to use [Gruff](https://github.com/topfunky/gruff) to render some graphics inside prawn documents.

I want to avoid the delay of writing images to the disk only for them to be read by Prawn.

Gruff offers the [to_blob method](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/topfunky/gruff/Gruff/Base#to_blob-instance_method) that renders the graph image as a blob in memory, but looking at the [prawn manual](http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/manual.pdf) image section, it only gives us a way to render images directly from files.

Am I missing something? Is there a way to render it from memory?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should be able pass the image data as a StringIO

```
require 'stringio'
require 'pdf'

Prawn::Example.generate("foo.pdf") do |pdf|
  data = StringIO.new(render_my_image_to_a_string)
  pdf.image(data)
end
```

Comment: Thank you! Works great with Barby for barcode generation.

Comment: just to add to this still working response : if you are storing your blob as `data:image/png;base64,` then see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35517769/6324558) to get your `render_my_image_to_a_string`