# Ruby on Rails - Transform base64 into image file without saving to use in multipart API call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, base64, multipartform-data

I'm using RoR and I have a base 64 encoded image `image_base64 = "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZ..."`.

An API asks me to upload it as JPG file in a multipart/form-data parameter - e.g `curl -X POST -F "images_file=@my_image.jpg"`

I know how to turn the base 64 image into a file that would be saved somewhere (like in [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160741/how-to-save-a-base64-string-as-an-image-using-ruby)), but I don't really want to be saving and deleting files, just create one on the fly. How can I do that?