# Creating image file from base64 data

Tags: ruby, base64, jpeg, binmode

I have a base64 encoded image data . I am pasting the first few characters

```
string='data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD     /2wBDAAYEBQYFBAYGBQYHBwYIChAKCgkJChQODwwQFxQYGBcUFhYaHSUfGhsjHBYWICwgIyYnKSopG   R8tMC0oMCUoKSj/2wBDAQcHBwoIChMKChMoGhYaKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgo......'
```

I am doing following to it in ruby

```
decoded_string=Base64.decode64 string
output_file = Tempfile.new(['image','.jpeg'])
output_file.binmode
output_file.write image
```

After this when I am opening 'image.jpeg', It is giving error

```
Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x75 0xab)
```

I also tried

```
File.open('a.jpeg', 'wb') do|f|
   f.write decoded_string
end
```

In this case also, I got the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' at the beginning of encoded string was causing this problem. I just had to remove that and then everything worked fine.

Comment: After trimming the `'data:image/jpeg;base64,'` portion, did you do `File.open` or the `output_file.write` bit?

Answer (score 3):

```
File.open('shipping_label.gif', 'wb') do|f|
  f.write(Base64.decode64(base_64_encoded_data))
end
```

This answer is from: [How to save a base64 string as an image using ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160741/how-to-save-a-base64-string-as-an-image-using-ruby)

Comment: You should vote to close the question if you think this is a duplicate.

Comment: Question was not duplicate. I was already using binary mode for writing the file. My problem were the first 23 characters of the encoded string i.e 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' so i just had to remove them and then decode it.