# Convert base64 pdf string into an image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, imagemagick, rmagick

I have tried the approach in 
[this example and the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43248603/creating-image-file-from-base64-data)

I still continue to receive a blank image when I render it. I need to generate a png file from this base64 string. The label_string is the base64 encoded pdf that I receive from a shipping label creater.

```
file = Tempfile.new(['order', '.png'])
        File.open(file.path.to_s, 'wb') do |f|
          f.write(Base64.decode64(label_string))
        end
        pdf = Services::Invoices::Pdf.new(invoice).process(file.path)
        file.unlink
        pdf
```

here is my label_string

```
"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"
```

UPDATE: I found a similar problem at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16168798/low-quality-when-converting-pdf-to-jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Imagemagick, you can do that with the INLINE: input structure. See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#inline. For example:

```
convert 'inline:data:image/png;base64,
R0lGODlhIAAgAPIEAAAAAB6Q/76+vvXes////wAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAAAUALAAA
AAAgACAAAAOBWLrc/jDKCYG1NBcwegeaxHkeGD4j+Z1OWl4Yu6mAYAu1ebpwL/OE
YCDA0YWAQuJqRwsSeEyaRTUwTlxUqjUymmZpmeI3u62Mv+XWmUzBrpeit7YtB1/r
pTAefv942UcXVX9+MjNVfheGCl18i4ddjwwpPjEslFKDUWeRGj2fnw0JADs=
'  b64_noseguy.png
```

[image]

Comment: What would be the way to enter this line into a program for ruby?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know as I do not use Ruby. Just a guess but try the same command as at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43248603/creating-image-file-from-base64-data but use my string above in place of the one in that example.

Answer (score 1):

```
        file1 = Tempfile.new(['order', '.pdf'])
        File.open(file1.path.to_s, 'wb') do |f|
          f.write(Base64.decode64(label_string))
        end
        file = Tempfile.new(['order', '.png'])
        im = Magick::Image.from_blob(open(file1.path.to_s).read).first
        im.write(file.path.to_s)
        pdf = Services::Invoices::Pdf.new(invoice).process(file.path)
        file.unlink
        pdf
```

This works, however; it does not seem like it would be the best solution.