# Ruby On rails xml to image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, paperclip, nokogiri

I have an xml file attached to an email I want to convert it into image and save it via paperclip. 
I first read it from my mail inbox:

```
@doc = Nokogiri::XML(attachment.body.decoded)
```

this is the @doc :

```
#<Nokogiri::XML::Document:0x3fe1a80c8874 name="document" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fe1a80c875c name="Letter" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x3fe1a80c8720 href="http://www.irica.com/ECE/1383-12/SendSchema"> children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fe1a4376138 "\n">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fe1a80c8360 name="Protocol" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x3fe1a80c8720 href="http://www.irica.com/ECE/1383-12/SendSchema"> attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fe1a4376034 name="Name" value="ECE">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fe1a4376020 name="Version" value="1.01">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fe1ac053804 "\n">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fe1a440e190 name="Software" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x3fe1a80c8720 href="http://www.irica.com/ECE/1383-12/SendSchema"> attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fe1ac053700 name="SoftwareDeveloper" value="NegarehSoft.">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fe1ac0536ec name="Version" value="4.0">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fe1ac0536d8 name="GUID" value="3B2AD369-3EB7-4b1f-A69F-A5C28CB7E265">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fe1ac052cd8 "\n">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fe1a84ffdac name="Sender" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x3fe1a80c8720 href="http://www.irica.com/ECE/1383-12/SendSchema"> attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fe1ac052bd4 name="Organization" value="سازمان تنظيم مقررات و ارتباطات راديويي">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fe1ac052bc0 name="Department" value="دفتر برنامه،بودجه،فناوري و تحول اداري">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fe1ac052bac name="Position">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fe1ac052b98 name="Name" value="چهره سا-ايمان - كارشناس دفتر فناوري اطلاعات">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fe1ac052b84 name="Code" value="2721560123">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fe1a4367cf0 "\n">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fe1a84feb78 name="Receiver" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x3fe1a80c8720 href="http://www.irica.com/ECE/1383-12/SendSchema"> attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fe1a4367bc4 name="Organization" value="شرکت خدمات ارتباطي ايرانسل-ارسال الکترونيکي">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fe1a4367bb0 name="Department" value="شرکت خدمات ارتباطي ايرانسل-ارسال الکترونيکي">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fe1a4367b9c name="Position">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fe1a4367b88 name="Name" value="دبيرخانه - شرکت خدمات ارتباطي ايرانسل">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fe1a4367b74 name="Code" value="8888888888">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fe1a4367b4c name="ReceiveType" value="Origin">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fe1a4366abc "\n">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fe1a440b8b4 name="LetterNo" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x3fe1a80c8720 href="http://www.irica.com/ECE/1383-12/SendSchema"> children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fe1a440b7ec "101/9/1/31562">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fe1a43664b8 "\n">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fe1a440b10c name="LetterDateTime" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x3fe1a80c8720 href="http://www.irica.com/ECE/1383-12/SendSchema"> attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fe1a43663b4 name="ShowAs" value="gregorian">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fe1a440b044 "2016-08-08T12:35:09">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fe1a43f9bf0 "\n">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fe1a43f9b3c name="RelatedLetters" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x3fe1a80c8720 href="http://www.irica.com/ECE/1383-12/SendSchema">>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fe1a43f97a4 "\n">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fe1a43f96f0 name="Subject" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x3fe1a80c8720 href="http://www.irica.com/ECE/1383-12/SendSchema"> children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fe1a43f9344 "\n\t">, #<Nokogiri::XML::CDATA:0x3fe1a43f9290 "تست ece مورخ 95/5/18">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fe1a43f91dc "\n">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fe1a43f9038 "\n">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fe1a440a950 name="Priority" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x3fe1a80c8720 href="http://www.irica.com/ECE/1383-12/SendSchema"> attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fe1a43f8f34 name="Name" value="عادي">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fe1a43f8f20 name="Code" value="21">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fe1a43f8728 "\n">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fe1a440a478 name="Classification" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x3fe1a80c8720 href="http://www.irica.com/ECE/1383-12/SendSchema"> attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fe1a43f8624 name="Name" value="عادي">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fe1a43f8610 name="Code" value="0">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fe1a42e5df4 "\n">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fe1a42e5d40 name="Keywords" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x3fe1a80c8720 href="http://www.irica.com/ECE/1383-12/SendSchema">>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fe1a42e5980 "\n">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fe1a42e58b8 name="Origins" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x3fe1a80c8720 href="http://www.irica.com/ECE/1383-12/SendSchema"> children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fe1a42e550c "\n\t">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fe1a42e5458 name="Origin" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x3fe1a80c8720 href="http://www.irica.com/ECE/1383-12/SendSchema"> attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fe1a42e53f4 name="ContentType" value="image/tiff">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fe1a42e53e0 name="Extension" value="TIF">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fe1a42e53cc name="Description" value="Letter.tif">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fe1a42e49a4 "\n\t\t">, #<Nokogiri::XML::CDATA:0x3fe1a42e48dc "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">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fe1a42e4828 "\n\t">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fe1a42e4684 "\n">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fe1a42e44e0 "\n">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fe1a42e442c name="Attachments" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x3fe1a80c8720 href="http://www.irica.com/ECE/1383-12/SendSchema">>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fe1a42e401c "\n">]>]>
```

I want to save it as an image something like this:

```
data = StringIO.new(Base64.decode64(@doc))
data.class_eval do
    attr_accessor :content_type, :original_filename
end
@attch = Attachment.create(picture: data)
```

But it's wrong I think and I get errors.

```
ERROR -- : /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/base64.rb:59:in `decode64'
```

Is there any way I can do this conversion with nokogiri or paperclip ?

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160741/how-to-save-a-base64-string-as-an-image-using-ruby#1161082

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio I checked it before ! didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the XML file I found an attachment tag in which was its own image ! So I did this :

```
@doc.css('Attachments').each do |attachment|
    if attachment.at("Attachment").present?
        data_xml = attachment.at("Attachment")

        base64format = data_xml.text
        decoded_data = Base64.decode64(base64format)
        data = StringIO.new(decoded_data)
        data.class_eval do
            attr_accessor :content_type, :original_filename
        end
        data.content_type = "image/tiff"
        @document = @ece.documents.create(picture: data)
    end
end
```

And it's fine.