# How to attach Base64 image to Active Storage object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, base64, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I can attach a png image from disc by and everything works just fine:

```
obj.attachment.attach(
  io: File.open('dog.png'),
  filename: "image_name",
  content_type: "image/png"
)
```

But it doesn't work giving result like too tiny empty square when I save a Base64 png image which encoded into `String` something like that `"data:image/png;base64,iVB**..REST OF DATA..**kSuQmCC"` by:

```
obj.attachment.attach(
  io: StringIO.new(encoded_base_sixty_four_img),
  filename: "image_name",
  content_type: "image/png"
)
```

Also I tried to decoded it but gives the same error:

```
decoded_base_sixty_four_img = Base64.decode64(encoded_base_sixty_four_img)
obj.attachment.attach(
  io: StringIO.new(decoded_base_sixty_four_img),
  filename: "image_name",
  content_type: "image/png"
)
```

Also tried writing this decoded value into a `File` but nothing worked too giving blank image result:

```
file = file.write(decoded_base_sixty_four_img)
obj.attachment.attach(
  io: file,
  filename: "image_name",
  content_type: "image/png"
)
```

So any other thoughts?

Comment: The `data:image/png;base64=` part is for a `data:` inline URL, and is not something `Base64.decode64` can deal with. You need to strip that part off first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to @tadman, `data:image/png;base64,` part can't be handled by `Base64.decode64` when I stripped it off everything worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me.

```
          Model.create!(
            product: product,
            image: { 
              io: StringIO.new(Base64.decode64(params[:base_64_image].split(',')[1])),
              content_type: 'image/jpeg',
              filename: 'image.jpeg'
            }
          )
```